# Developing an ansible module, what's the easiest way of detecting which become_method is in use?

Tags: ansible

As part of a python module, I need to change to another given user (other than the originating become_user) to perform an operation.
Is there an easy way to query what become-method is in operation so I can determine whether to use sudo, su etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can't find it from a module, but if you write an action_plugin, you can get it from `play_context.become_method`. You could then have your action_plugin exec your module and pass the necessary become info to it.